# Storing lambda without templatizing class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
class what {
    template<class F>
    what(F&& f) {}
};
```

Here `F` is a lambda, how to store it in a member-variable without templatizing the whole class?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the variable? Can you post your whole code if you do templatize the class?

Comment: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `std::function` is for. Suppose you want `what` to store a callable that takes an `int` as an argument and returns `void`. Then you would write something like this:

```
class what
{
  public:
    template<class T>
    what(T&& t) : callback(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

  private:
    std::function<void(int)> callback;
};
```

You could even make the constructor itself not a template:

```
class what
{
  public:
    what(std::function<void(int)> callback) : callback(std::move(callback)) {}

  private:
    std::function<void(int)> callback;
};
```

Comment: what if you dont know the type beforehand?

Comment: @PnotNP how are you going to use the stored callable if you don't know what argument types it expects?

Comment: It could be one of the few known types, its just not know what type before hand

Comment: @PnotNP Can you edit your question to add detail about what types you need to support and how your class is intended to be used?